# getting an 500 error while passing the json. (PHP curl /Postman)

Tags: php, json, postman, php-curl

Sample json body:-

```
{
 "worknotes": "<div>In this case, Employee to visit&nbsp;<a title="https://test.test.com/#/home" href="https://test.test.com/#/home" rel="noreferrer noopener" target="_blank">https://travel.test.com/#/home</a>&nbsp;,&nbsp;click on help and log a case for support.<br /></div>"

}
```

Passing the content-type  as application/json

receiving the 500 internal server error . Any idea how I can parse this

Comment: I'm not sure if this sample is real, but if so, I can tell you that it's not a valid json data, quotes must be escaped, so you can't parse it. Additionally, your question lacks many details, such as how the data is sent, how the server processes it. You also need to figure out whether the 500 error is returned by the http server or php code.

Comment: misuse of `"`: You used them as string separator and inside the string without \. The error log should tell this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your JSON Is Invalid**

**Try this**

```
{
 "worknotes": "<div>In this case, Employee to visit&nbsp;<a title=\"https://test.test.com/#/home\" href=\"https://test.test.com/#/home\" rel=\"noreferrer noopener\" target=\"_blank\">https://travel.test.com/#/home</a>&nbsp;,&nbsp;click on help and log a case for support.<br /></div>"

}
```